# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'albumentations'

Tags: python, pytorch, albumentations

I tried to install this package of 'albumentations' through

`pip install --upgrade albumentations` and `pip install albumentations --user`

Python version 3.9.0, on a local machine (not in Google Colab or Kaggle).

It installs:

`Successfully installed albumentations-1.3.1 imageio-2.31.1 joblib-1.3.1 lazy_loader-0.3 opencv-python-headless-4.8.0.74 qudida-0.0.4 scikit-image-0.21.0 scikit-learn-1.3.0`

But still, it shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 3
      1 # ! pip install --upgrade albumentations
      2 get_ipython().system(' pip install albumentations --user')
----> 3 import albumentations
      4 import albumentations.pytorch

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'albumentations'
```

What should I do to install this?

Comment: Is it available in your `site-packages` directory? If your OS is Windows, you'll find it in `C:\Users\user_name\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages`.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. I restarted the kernel after `pip install albumentations --user` and it works

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
python -m pip install albumentations
```